# Converting R data frame with RDS package: recruitment id error?

Tags: r, survey

I am using the RDS package for respondent-driven sampling survey data. I want to convert a regular R data frame to an rds.data.frame. To do so, I have been trying to use the as.rds.data.frame function from RDS.

Here is an excerpted section of my data frame, where the first case (id=1) is the 'seed' respondent (who has no recruiter). It contains the variables: id (respondent id number), recruit.id(id number of respondent who recruited him/her), netsize (respondent's network size) and population (estimate of whole population size).

```
     df<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                    recruit.id=c(-1,1,1,2,2,4,5,3,8,3),
                    netsize=c(6,6,6,5,5,4,4,3,4,6), population=rep(22,000, 10))
```

I then (try to) apply the relevant function:

```
   new.df <-as.rds.data.frame(df,id=df$id, 
                              recruiter.id=df$recruit.id,
                              network.size=df$netsize,
                              population.size=df$population, 
                              max.coupons=2)
```

I get the error message:

> Error in as.rds.data.frame(df, id = df$id, recruiter.id = df$recruit.id,: Invalid id

and the warning

> In addition: Warning message:In if (!(id %in% names(x))) stop("Invalid id") : 
>        the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I have tried assigning various 'recruiter id' values for seed participants, including -1,0 or their own id number but I still get the same message. I have also tried eliminating function arguments (coupon.max, population) or deleting seed respondents, but I still get the same message.

Package documentation says the function will fail if recruitment information is incomplete. As far as I can tell, this is not the case.

I am new to this, so if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
 colnames(df)[2:4] <- c("recruiter.id", "network.size.variable", "population.size")
 as.rds.data.frame(df,max.coupons=2)
```

This gives a result with a warning

```
 as.rds.data.frame(df, id="id", recruiter.id="recruit.id",
    network.size="netsize", population.size="population", max.coupons=2)
  # An object of class "rds.data.frame"

 #id:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

 #recruiter.id:  -1 1 1 2 2 4 5 3 8 3 

 #   id recruit.id netsize population
 #1   1         -1       6         22
 #2   2          1       6         22
 #3   3          1       6         22
 #4   4          2       5         22
 #5   5          2       5         22
 #6   6          4       4         22
 #7   7          5       4         22
 #8   8          3       3         22
 #9   9          8       4         22
 #10 10          3       6         22


# Warning message:
#In as.rds.data.frame(df, id = "id", recruiter.id = "recruit.id",  :
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Re-naming the data frame variables works. Thank you!